# Передача массива char[] по сети через сокет Беркли и прием через Java Socket

Tags: java, c, сокет, unix-socket

Суть такова -  есть клиент(написанный на Си) и есть сервер, написанный на Java. Клиент передает строку типа char[] через сокет, сервер принимает строку и записывает в String[] и выдает "EOFEXception". Я так почитал что это несоответствие типов данных, проблема в том что у меня сервер принимает в UTF формате, а клиент, честно говоря я даже не знаю, возможно ASKII использует код. В общем ниже будет код клиента и сервера, спасибо за помощь.
P.S. Клиент работает в Debian.И нужна именно кодировка символов UTF, потому что они должны быть читабельные.

Client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
char message[2048];
char buf[sizeof(message)];
int port,ch;

int sock;                 // дескриптор сокета
struct sockaddr_in addr; // структура с адресом
port = 7000;
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // создание TCP-сокета
if(sock < 0)
{
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
}

// Указываем параметры сервера//--------------------------------------------
addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // домены Internet
addr.sin_port = htons(port); // или любой другой порт...
addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.102");
if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) // установка 
соединения с сервером
{
    perror("Подключение");
    exit(2);
}

while(1){//WHILE <---
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
printf("Введите сообщение серверу(Для выхода:exit): "); 
if (!strcmp(gets(message), "exit")){close(sock);return 0;}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

printf("отправка сообщения на сервер...\n");
send(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0); // отправка сообщения на сервер
int bytes_read = 0;
//printf("Ожидание сообщения\n");
//bytes_read = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(message), 0);
//printf("Получено %d bytes\tСообщение: %s\n", bytes_read, buf); // прием 
сообщения от сервера


}//END_WHILE

return 0;

}
```

Server:

```
package server;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

class InputOutput {

String InputData() {

}

 void OutputDataClient() {

 }
 }


class SSocket {

int port = 7000; // 1025 ... 65535

void EnableAndLoad() {

   try {
    ServerSocket servsocket = new ServerSocket(port); // создание сокета
    System.out.println("Ожидание клиента");

    Socket socket = servsocket.accept(); // Ожидание коннекта
    System.out.println("Клиент подключен");
    System.out.println();

    InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
    String line = null;
    int counter =0;
    while(true) {

       line = in.readUTF(); // ожидание строки от клиента
        System.out.println("Клиент: " + line);
        String[] sensorBuffer = line.split(" ",6);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sensorBuffer));
        //out.writeUTF(line); // отсылаем клиенту обратно строку текста
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("Ожидание следующей строки");
        System.out.println();
        counter++;
        if(counter == 2) { //Выход из бесконечного цикла
            break;
        }
    }

  } catch(Exception exc) { 
      System.out.println("Exception" + exc);

   //return "StringTest";
}
}

}

public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputOutput enter = new InputOutput();
        SSocket connect_ = new SSocket();

        connect_.EnableAndLoad();
        //enter.InputData();
        //enter.OutputData();
        //enter.OutputDataClient();


}

}
```

В идеале конечно это все дело должно еще принимать данные с датчика DHT11 через GPIO, но это уже другая история))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываем доку на [readUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF()) и читаем, что именно делает эта функция. А она вначале читает два байта для того, что бы узнать длину.

Сишний код просто отправляет строку. Он не отправляет ни длину, ни какого-то спецсимвола в конце (например, перевод строки или ноль), что бы вызывающий код мог "догадаться", сколько читать.

Сам TCP так устроен, что он гарантирует последовательность байт, но не более. То есть, если с одной стороны отправить две посылки по 100 байт, то с другой стороны может прийти два раза по одному байту, а потом 198. И это **законно и по спекам**.

Что же делать? Наиболее простой способ - на передающей стороне писать вначале размер строки. Думаю, после этого на стороне жавы все прочитается. Но это скользкий путь.

Правильный способ - разработать протокол. К примеру, вначале размер, потом строка. Или строка ограничена переводом строки (удобно в telnet отлаживать). Или клиент-сервер обмениваются json/xml.

**UPD**

забыл дописать самое главное - почему возникает ошибка EOFEXception. `readUTF` читает первые два байта и пытается интерпретировать их как 2-байта беззнаковое целое. А там скорее всего будут какие-то символы (например, aa), они будут прочитаны как число (0x6161 = 24929) и дальше метод пытается прочитать такое-кол-во символов. А их там точно нет (вряд ли Вы там набили 30к текста в 2кбайтную строку). И бедная java подождав, понимает, что данных нет и она вынуждена читать за пределами стрима. Даже если бы ввели самые минимальные печатные символы (пробелы), это было бы как минимум 8224 байта.

Comment: Т.е. можно решить эту проблему добавлением в передаваемый массив char[] символ окончания строки, просто у меня выхода другого нет - приходится использовать Си. И/или все таки нужно добавить размер строки в первые два байта?

Comment: можно по разному. Главное - синхронно. Но readUTF я бы не использовал - нужно явное чтения-запись.

Если в передаваемый массив добавить признак конца строки, java код нужно будет модифицировать соответствующим образом.

Comment: Тогда возможно ли использовать readLine и сделать проверку на наличие символа конца строки(если такого не предусмотрено автоматически)? Дабы не заморачиваться с readUTF?

Comment: должно работать. Главное не забывать передавать перевод строки.

Comment: Помогло это мне, но теперь на сервере первый раз принимает нормально строку, а второй - набор символов рандомный.

Comment: теперь нужно запускать wireshark/tcpdump и смотреть, что там бежит

Comment: Нашел все пакеты, которые передавались каждую из двух попыток, в первом случае оба пакета успешно передались а во втором передача с клиента на сервер помечена красным, честно говоря мои знания Вайршарка совсем уж малы чтобы анализировать содержимое пакетов.

Comment: Я нашел то, что передает клиент, там моя строка + рандомный набор символов. Хотя я просто строку передаю, нигде ее не меняя.

Comment: Похоже просто забыли правильно конец занулить и передать правильный размер.

Comment: Я просто сейчас попытаюсь добавить динамическую строку, я думаю это решит проблему.

Comment: Минимальный символ, который можно ввести — TAB, но это не отменяет сказанного вами.